# list is not callable error in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, runtime-error

i have this part of a sript that converts a number of days traveled into a month and day for a date() function, I run it though and it give me a list is not callable error and says that the problem is in the line that holds the date() function

```
def current_date(days_traveled):
    #list months
    dt=days_traveled+1
    if dt<=30:
        month=4
        day=dt
    if (dt>=31) and (dt<=61):
        month=5
        day=dt-30
    if (dt>=62) and (dt<=91):
        month=6
        day=dt-61
    if (dt>=92) and (dt<=122):
        month=7
        day=dt-91
    if (dt>=123) and (dt<=153):
        month=8
        day=dt-122
    if (dt>=154) and (dt<=183):
        month=9
        day=dt-153
    if (dt>=184) and (dt<=214):
        month=10
        day=dt-183
    if (dt>=215) and (dt<=244):
        month=11
        day=dt-214
    if (dt>=245) and (dt<=275):
        month=12
        day=dt-244
    year=date(1843,month,day) >>>error is here
    weekday=year.weekday()
    weekday_list=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    current_day=weekday_list[weekday]
    date_list=[]
    date_list.append(year)
    date_list.append(weekday)
    date_list.append(current_day)
    return date_list
```

I imagine that is some simple naming error, but I don't know what it is.
Thanks

Comment: `date` is not a built-in function: `from datetime import date`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary after importing date, the code works for me. I wonder how OP managed to get the `list is not callable` error that he mentions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Global variable named `date`? If so, he'll have to rename it.

Comment: Do you know that in Python you can write `if 31 <= dt <= 61: ...`?

Comment: to start off, I know date is not a built in function, it is just imported outside of this function, I will double check and see if I have a variable named date, but I already checked through once, I did not know that you could format it like 31 <= dt <= 61, thanks fro that tip. It will save alot of time

Comment: `print(date)` right before the line causing the error and see if it's what it should be.

Comment: I was using the name elsewhere, that was the problem, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you got that error, but by doing `from datetime import date` your script works without any errors. That's not the problem though.

The problem is you're doing a lot of work to calculate something that python has built in. So I'm taking it your starting point is `01/04/1843`, right? All you need to do, is use python's `datetime` and `timedelta` objects in concentation and let python do the work for you. Then everything becomes much easier, with a lot less code, and less chances of making mistakes.

Like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
DEFAULT_DATE = datetime(1843, 4, 1) #this is a constant

def current_date(days_traveled):
    dt = DEFAULT_DATE + timedelta(days=days_traveled+1) #I don't know why +1, so I'm leaving it like that
    year = dt.year
    weekday = dt.weekday()
    current_day = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"][weekday]
    return [year, weekday, current_day]
```

I would've preferred using `datetime.strftime('%Y-%w-%A')` to get everything with one line, but that function doesn't work on dates prior to 1900 (and also, you'd get everything in string form, which may not be desirable).

Hope that helps =]

Comment: I found that problem in my text, I was using date as a variable elsewhere, but onto your example. Now that you have edited it makes a little more sense, I was wondering because I came out with weekday=6 which is sunday, I just have one question, how does the list with [weekday] work at the end of the one line, what is it doing exactly?

Comment: everything is working, thanks a lot, that saves me a lot of code

Comment: Sure thing. I saw that others helped you figure out how where the error was coming from. Regarding the part with `[weekday]` at the end, It's a simple slice, I'm just doing it all in one line, i.e `['a', 'b', 'c'][0]` will return `'a'`